# WordPress not using category.php file for custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm coding a WordPress theme on a staging site and I'm having an issue with having all of my posts display. I've set the static page for the blog to "News" in the setting > Reading option but when I go to the news page, the page is displaying using the index.php file instead of the category.php file that I have created. Template order should have index last if it can't find category or archive is my understanding.

I'm using the same coding on another site and it works correctly. I've put this new theme on that existing site and it works as it should. They are both on the same hosting company. I started a brand new WordPress instance and it's not working on that new instance either.

My template for page.php is working fine instead of defaulting to index.php

Also tried updating permalinks, checked file permissions, checked htaccess file for rewrite conditions.

So what am I missing?

category.php code

```
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-posts', get_post_format() ); ?>

  <?php endwhile; else : ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>

  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php echo paginate_links(); ?>
```

Comment: Let’s start with “when I go to the news page”. When I hear that, I think of a plural entity, the single of what WordPress calls a Post Type, and the plural being represented by an archive page, not a category. Can you test and confirm this?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the plural - Lots of posts on the one page, not a single post page.

Comment: You want an [archive template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) then.

Comment: I added an archive.php but same result, it's still just using index.php but my homepage is using front-page.php and my pages are using page.php

Comment: Is it some database thing?

Comment: Also, is your "News" actually just the built-in "Post" type, or is it a CPT?

Comment: Built in post type. https://staging2.gcap.com.au/news/ Under settings > Reading I have the posts page set to News but you can see on that page where I've put Index Template to show it's not using archive.php or category.php. Been through everything with the web host and they reckon everything is fine environment and wordpress installation wise. The only thing I can think of is something with th database from a previous theme or something.

Comment: Couldn't work it just. Just built a page template to handle all posts.